# How to save a pdf as an object in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.5

I'm creating a program that allows a user to take a `.pdf` from their computer and save it to a predetermined location on a shared server. The server is a file share system not SQL.

I'm trying to figure out how to fix it to where all they have to do is press `btnUpload` or `btnUpdate` then the OpenFileDialog will open, they select the `.pdf` and then it automatically saves to the predetermined location.

The issue I'm running into is how do I save the opened pdf as an object so that I can then save it to the location? Or am I go about this in the wrong direction?

Platform: C# Winform / WPF

Comment: It's a binary blob, it doesn't need any specific object. Just a byte array, if you need to transfer it and not just copy the file via filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The one you linked was for http, this is c# winform. Sami, so just convert into a byte array? And then use save file for that?

Comment: *this is c# winform* - Please update your question. From the question itself it was not clear that any web technology is involved at all.

Comment: Done, thank you! Sorry about that